# Select row from table where same value in another column for every row

Tags: oracle, plsql

I want to find all IDs in a table where 'FALSE' is the value in another column  for every row with that ID. In the screen cap here:

[image]

I only want to get back 'AFERRIERA' and 'AHANLON' because for every row that is in the column IDENTITY the column "METHOD_DEFAULT' is 'FALSE'

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's OK I resolved it:

```
SELECT DISTINCT IDENTITY
  FROM PERSON_INFO_COMM_METHOD2 t
 WHERE METHOD_DEFAULT = 'FALSE'
   AND NOT EXISTS (SELECT * FROM PERSON_INFO_COMM_METHOD2 WHERE METHOD_DEFAULT <> 'FALSE' 
   AND IDENTITY = t.IDENTITY)
```

Comment: Yeah I tried to but it says I can't do that for two days